# Create a QueryFilter every time a DbContext is created

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have defined an efcore model which is as follows

```cs
public abstract class HumanCapitalManagementContext : DbContext
{
    protected readonly CurrentUser _currentUser;
    protected HumanCapitalManagementContext(DbContextOptions options, CurrentUser currentUser) : base(options)
    {
        _currentUser = currentUser;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.ApplyQueryFilters<IDeleted>(x => x.DeletedAt == null);

        if(_currentUser.IsAuthenticated)
            modelBuilder.ApplyQueryFilters<ICompany>(x =>  x.CompanyId == 1);
    }
}
```

I am stuck here that the OnModelCreating method is executed only 1 time and the Context is created in the Scope and for each http request.

I need the OnModelCreating method to be executed every time the DbContext is created, but I can't find a solution.

My question is, does anyone have a solution so that I can set the OnModelCreating method for each time the Context is created or access ModelBuilder and create filters in my ctor??

I read the efcore documentation, but I only found that this method can only be executed once

I asked gpt chat for help, but it gave me wrong answers

I tried to fix the problem by using linq, but it always compares 0 if there is no authentication.

```cs
modelBuilder.ApplyQueryFilters<ICompany>(x => _currentUser.IsAuthenticated ? x.CompanyId == 1 : true);
```

I have been looking for a solution for 4 months now, but I have not found anything

Comment: *I need the OnModelCreating method to be executed every time the DbContext is created* -- That's impossible. It's EF behavior to do this once, for good reasons. That said, what is this `ApplyQueryFilters` method? It's not a native EF method.

Comment: Have your tried the solution provided? Do you still have any further concern on this?

Answer (score 0):

`OnModelCreating` is a method that is called only once for each DbContext class and cannot be changed. However, there is a way to solve your problem.

EF Core allows you to use only the properties of DbContexts in query filters. Therefore, you need to create them:

```cs
public abstract class HumanCapitalManagementContext : DbContext
{
    protected readonly CurrentUser _currentUser;
    protected HumanCapitalManagementContext(DbContextOptions options, CurrentUser currentUser) : base(options)
    {
        _currentUser = currentUser;
    }

    public bool IsAuthenticatedUser => _currentUser.IsAuthenticated;

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.ApplyQueryFilters<IDeleted>(x => x.DeletedAt == null);
        modelBuilder.ApplyQueryFilters<ICompany>(x => IsAuthenticatedUser ? x.CompanyId == 1 : true);
    }
}
```